# C matrix function segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, matrix, segmentation-fault

I have this piece of code that gives me SEGMENTATION FAULT when the function **loadRow(tmpPop,bestOf4Route,k,n);** is called the fifth time. In particular, the function is called correctly at the first loop of the fro (when p=3). It' all ok for every value of k. I don't understand why, the second time I execute the loop (p=7), the first time is called (k=0), it return SEGMENTATION F when try to access the matric tmpPop.

```
      randperm(popSize,randomOrder);
      for(p = 3;p<popSize;p+=4)
      {
        load_rtes(rtes,pop,randomOrder,n,p);
        load_dists(dists,totalDist,randomOrder,p);
        find_min(dists, 4,&m,&idx);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)  bestOf4Route[j]=rtes[j][idx];
        X = rand_range(1,5);
        Y = rand_range(1,5);
        for(k =0;k<4;k++) //Mutate the Best to get Three New Routes
        {
            loadRow(tmpPop,bestOf4Route,k,n);

            switch(k)
            {
                case 1: //Flip
                    flipMutation(tmpPop,k,X,Y);
                    break;
                case 2: //Swap
                    swapMutation(tmpPop,k,X,Y);
                    break;
                case 3: //Slide
                    slideMutation(tmpPop,k,X,Y);
                    break;
            }
        }
        loadnewPop(newPop,tmpPop,p,n);
    }
```

The function is:

```
void loadRow(int **mat,int *array,int k,int size)
{
   int j;

   for(j=0;j<size;j++)
   {
       mat[j][k] = array[j];
   }
}
```

The parameters are:

> popSize = 16

```
n= 8

// create 4 x N matrix

tmpPop = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

if(tmpPop==NULL) return 1;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

  tmpPop[i] = (int*)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

  if(tmpPop[i]==NULL) return 1;
}

// Creates an array of n

bestOf4Route = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

if(bestOf4Route==NULL) return 1;

clear_array(bestOf4Route,n);
```

And her it is the debug result:

> 00401865  loadRow(mat=0x3e1438, array=0x3e1698, k=0, size=8)

```
void load_rtes(int **rtes,int **pop,int *randomOrder, int n,int p)
{
  int i,j,r;

  for(i=p-3;i<=p;i++)
  {
    //thakes the i element of randomOrder and use it as index for the pop row
    r=randomOrder[i];
    // copy the pop row in rtes
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        rtes[j][i]=pop[j][r];
    }
  }
}

void randperm(int n,int *perm)
{
   int i, j, t;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    perm[i] = i;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    j = rand()%(n-i)+i;
    t = perm[j];
    perm[j] = perm[i];
    perm[i] = t;
}
}
```

Comment: could you also post the function `load_rtes()`? You use that indirectly to populate `tmpPop`.

Comment: Ok, I've added it to the question!

Comment: And now the code where you initialize `randomOrder`:) You'll need to show us **all** of the code that somehow interacts with that `loadRow` function.

Comment: Are you sure that they don't close my question if I do that? I've added it :) It's the function randperm() called before the for loop

Comment: Do you also get a Segfault if you comment the line `loadnewPop(newPop,tmpPop,p,n);`?

Comment: Yes...it's nonsense...the memory seems ok, no null pointer, no unitialized variables...I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

A Segfault means that you accessed a memory region you weren't allowed to access. This can happen quite easily when doing pointer arithmetic wrong. So, although I can't tell you where the problem exactly lies, I suggest that you use a good debugger or some `printf()` statements to look at `k`, `n` and `j` to see if you exceed the bounds of the matrix / array. Also, you'll need to make sure that you allocated the right amount of memory.

Comment: I used the debugger of code::blocks and i printed with printf the value of j, matrix[j][k] and array[j] and they are all ok! The strange thing is that the function is called 4 times and nothing goes wrong. Then, when it's called in a new loop of the for (so k turn to 0 again) I can't access the matrix ( in j=0, so in matrix [j][k]) something goes wrong. But as u can see from the debug I've posted, the pointer to the matrix isn't null and j = 0. Really i'm stuck and confused